# CoffeeScript re-arranges method call parenthesis, why?

Tags: coffeescript

I have written this in CoffeeScript:

`expect (@controllerInstance[fn]).toHaveBeenCalled()`

and it's been compiled to this:

`return expect(this.controllerInstance[fn].toHaveBeenCalled());`

Why has it re-arranged the method call parenthesis? And how would I make it compile to what I want?

what I need to see is:

`expect(this.controllerInstance[fn]).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses serve two purposes in CoffeeScript:

1. Expression grouping, e.g. `(6 + 11) * 23` or `f (-> 6), (-> 11)`.
2. Function calling, e.g. `f()`, `g('pancakes')`.

Since parentheses are sometimes optional in a function call, there is some ambiguity in:

```
f (expr)
```

Are those parentheses being used to call `f` with `expr` as its argument or are the parentheses really a part of `f`'s argument? CoffeeScript chooses the latter interpretation.

You'll see similar problems if write:

```
f (x) + 1
```

CoffeeScript sees that as:

```
f((x) + 1)
```

Similarly, if you write:

```
f (x, y)
```

you'll get an `unexpected ,` error; CoffeeScript doesn't have a comma operator so `x, y` is not a valid expression.

You can remove the ambiguity by removing the whitespace before the opening parenthesis:

```
expect(@controllerInstance[fn]).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Removing the space after `expect` forces CoffeeScript to view the parentheses around `@controllerInstance[fn]` to be seen as function-calling parentheses.